# Aligned memory in Swift 3

Tags: swift, posix, swift3

In previous versions of Swift, I have been able to use the `posix_memalign` function to allocate aligned memory to help optimize certain operations. Since upgrading to the Swift 3 beta (packed with Xcode 8 beta 2), it has been failing and I am not sure why. It could simply be an issue with the beta, or maybe I simply need to change how I am interface with the function.

The sample code that I have been using for investigating the issue is shown below. (It tries to allocate a buffer of floating point numbers that is 16K aligned.)

```
var pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>? = nil
let alignment: Int = 0x4
let length: Int = bufferSize

let ret = posix_memalign(&pointer, alignment, length * sizeof(Float))

if ret != noErr {
    let err = String(validatingUTF8: strerror(ret)) ?? "unknown error"
    fatalError("Unable to allocate aligned memory: \(err).")
}
```

The `posix_memalign` fails with an "Invalid argument." message.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that my alignment was not a multiple of 8, but instead a multiple of 4, which is an invalid alignment (`posix_memalign` expects alignments to be a multiple of a the length of a `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>`).

Simply correcting my alignment fixed the issue.

More surprisingly, the code did work in Swift 2, but has stopped working in Swift 3 (the beta included with Xcode 8). The only related change has been the switch from allowing `UnsafeMutablePointer` to be nil in the previous version, while it now must be optional to reflect the fact that it can be nil.